# Adding an author after acceptance

Tags: authorship

After sending a paper for publication, in the scenario that the paper is accepted for publication, is there a possibility of adding an author, who was somehow mistakenly been left in the pdf that was sent to the journal? Assume that the authorship is not gifted here; the author has actually contributed quite significantly to the paper.

Comment: "somehow mistakenly been left in the pdf " left out?

Comment: A student of mine did this to me.  He/she submitted a paper of ours to a low ranking journal without my knowledge.   It got accepted, and he wanted to include me as a co-author so that I could pay for the page charges!  Even though there was clear evidence I was the supervisor, the work was from his/her PhD thesis, the publisher said no.   As an aside, you probably have a bigger problem: the left out author may claim authorship and ask the publisher to withdraw your paper!  In my case, I relinquished my authorship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convince the journal that it actually is a mistake as opposed to gift authorship.

If you do convince them then yes, you can add an author.

Comment: @OP The answer from Allure says all. Still, I would add that actually you must pursue this happy ending